# Using Windows commandline, how can I completely replace one folder with another?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

So far I have it to where I can copy all the files from `c:\Users\John\Folder1` to `c:\Users\John\Folder2`.

But I am looking to completely swap the folders.

e.g. Replace `c:\Users\John\Folder1`  with `c:\Users\John\SomeFolder\Folder1`.

I have this right now: `xcopy c:\Users\John\SomeFolder\* c:\Users\John\Folder1 /s /i`

This just copies all the files from the `c:\Users\John\SomeFolder\Folder1` to `c:\Users\John\Folder1` but leaves the files that had been there prior. I want the entire folder to be replaced. If the new folder I am copying no longer has those files, I want them deleted.

Sorry if this is confusing - any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a two step process: First erase all the files in the `old` folder and then copy the `new` folder contents into the `old` folder... It's the simplest approach, don't you think?

Comment: So delete `Folder1` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a batch file to do this.

**The pseudo-code:**

1. Erase contents of directory 1
2. Copy the contents from directory 1 to directory 2

**The code:**
Create a file called `swapFiles.bat` in your notepad, and enter the following code:

```
rd /s %1
mkdir %1
xcopy /s /i %2\* %1
```

***How to use it:***

```
swapFiles c:\Users\directory1 c:\Users\directory2
```

`directory1` is the `old` directory (i.e. the one that will be wiped out)

Hope this helps you

Comment: Nice! I'm going to try this tomorrow. I'll be sure to let everyone know how it worked out.

Comment: Wait... shouldn't #2 be "Copy the contents from directory 2 to directory 1"?

Comment: Your deleting the contents and then trying to copy it, you need it the other way around :)

Comment: This worked!
Thanks again!

Just in case anyone is wondering, here is how my commands look:

`rd /s \\psf\Home\Desktop\NewFolder\Test1`


`mkdir \\psf\Home\Desktop\NewFolder\Test1`


`xcopy /s /i \\psf\Home\Desktop\Test2\* \\psf\Home\Desktop\NewFolder`

The directory `\\psf\Home\Desktop\Test2\` has a folder named `Test1` as well, which replaces the folder `\\psf\Home\Desktop\NewFolder\Test1`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm completely missing your point, but would this not do the job? (example):

```
rename Folder1 transit
rename Folder2 Folder1
rename transit Folder2
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm completely new to this stuff so I have never heard of 'transit'. It never even came up when I googled :/

Comment: Transit is just an arbitrary name that I chose :)

Comment: My bad, I should have picked something obvious, like Temp.

Comment: But this doesn't really do anything besides rename the folders right?

I am trying to replace the entire contents of one directory with another that may be somewhere else entirely.

Comment: OK - renaming only works on the same drive, so you'll have to throw in some xcopy commands as well if you're going across such boundaries.

Comment: Yeah, what I plan on doing will be using different drives

Answer (score 1):

This will mirror the first folder to the second.

Be **very** careful that the paths are correct.

```
@echo off
robocopy "c:\Users\John\SomeFolder\Folder1" "c:\Users\John\Folder1" /mir
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to delete this folder c:\Users\John\SomeFolder before copying the folder1 if it is so this code may wok for you

```
@echo off

robocopy /s c:\Users\John\Folder1 c:\Users\John\SomeFolder\Folder1
rmdir /s /q c:\Users\John\Folder1
```

Comment: No I am looking to delete c:\Users\John\ **Folder1** and replace it with c:\Users\John\SomeFolder\Folder1.

So the directory containing the files will still be `c:\Users\John\Folder1`

Comment: I think now this code will delete the folder c:\Users\John\ Folder1 and gives the required result